# How to set custom attribute using eloquent using related model

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I have a eloquent query like this:

```
$partners = DeliveryPartner::where('active', 1)
    ->where('blocked', 0)
    ->whereHas('deliveryPartnerZipcodes', function ($query) use ($zip4pp) {
        $query->where('zipcode', $zip4pp);
    })
    ->with('deliveryPartnerImage')
    ->with(['deliveryPartnerTimes' => function($query) {
        //HERE I WANT TO SET A PROPERTY ON THE BASE COLLECTION USING INFO FROM THIS MODEL
    }])
    ->get();
```

In delivery times there are opening and closing times. Using these times I want to set a property called "**status**" on the parent like $parent->status = some value based on the data from delivery partner times.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model add a get attribute function:

```
public function getStatusAttribute() {
    return $this->delivery->opening . ' - ' . $this->delivery->closing;
}
```

Note that I am using relation with `Delivery` in order to calculate this attribute.
This way you dont need to do anything in the Eloquent query and can use `->status` on your result collection.